# Convert API requests to Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, intercom

This post is following my previous one ->
[How to turn Postman API's request into Apps Script code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73032346/how-to-turn-postman-apis-request-into-apps-script-code)

I'm trying to convert 3 API requests into a single piece of code via Google Apps Script.
The purpose is to export automatically a set of data from my CRM platform into Google Sheet.

Based on my CRM platform documentation, I need to do 3 API requests in order to get the final set of data I want:

- [Creating an export job](https://developers.intercom.com/intercom-api-reference/v0/reference/creating-an-export-job) (using a POST request)
- [Retrieve the job status](https://developers.intercom.com/intercom-api-reference/v0/reference/checking-the-status-of-the-job) from previous request (using GET request)
- [Retrieve the exported data](https://developers.intercom.com/intercom-api-reference/v0/reference/downloading-the-data) (using GET request)

Below is the code for the 1st API request (kindly provided by Tanaike):

```
function exportjob() {
  var url = 'https://api.intercom.io/export/content/data';
  var options = {
    "method": "post",
    "headers": {
      "Authorization": "Bearer 123456789",
      "Accept": "application/json",
    },
    "contentType": "application/json",
    "payload": JSON.stringify({
      "created_at_after": 1654041600,
      "created_at_before": 1656547200
    })
  }
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  console.log(response.getContentText())
}
```

The result of this request is the following

> Info  {"job_identifier":"5gf58ty4y5y45229r", "status":"pending", "download_url":"", "download_expires_at":""}

Next step is to add the 2 other API requests in my script (Retrieve the job status and retrieve the data).
However I have a couple of issues:

**For the 2nd API request**

- How do I include the job_identifier ID in my code? (given in the 1st request)

**For the 3rd API request**

- How do I retrieve the data with the URL provided in the 2nd API request?
- The data comes as ZIP file, how do I convert it to CSV so Google Sheet can open it?
- How do get the final set of data to be exported in a google sheet?

Apologies for the long post, I'm trying to summarize the [documentation from my CRM platform](https://developers.intercom.com/intercom-api-reference/v0/reference/downloading-the-data) as much as I can.
Any help on how to retrieve the job POST and retrieve the set of data to a google sheet via CSV would be highly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 1. About `For the 2nd API request`

If this is for [Retrieve a job status](https://developers.intercom.com/intercom-api-reference/v0/reference/checking-the-status-of-the-job), it seems that the sample curl command is as follows.

```
curl https://api.intercom.io/export/content/data/v5xsp8c19ji0s82 \
-X GET \
-H 'Authorization:Bearer <Your access token>'
-H 'Accept: application/json'
```

- It seems that the value of `job_identifier` can be retrieved from your 1st request shown in your question. [Ref](https://developers.intercom.com/intercom-api-reference/v0/reference/creating-an-export-job)
- When this request is done for the first time, it seems that `status` returns `pending`. By this, it seems that until `status` is changed to `complete`, it is required to wait. [Ref](https://developers.intercom.com/intercom-api-reference/v0/reference/export-job-model)

#### 2. About `For the 3rd API request`

If this is for [Retrieve the exported data](https://developers.intercom.com/intercom-api-reference/v0/reference/downloading-the-data), it seems that the sample curl command is as follows.

```
curl https://api.intercom.io/download/content/data/xyz1234 \
-X GET \
-H 'Authorization:Bearer <Your access token>' \
-H 'Accept: application/octet-stream’
```

In this case, the document says `Your exported message data will be streamed continuously back down to you in a gzipped CSV format.`. I thought that in this case, the returned data might be able to be ungzipped with `Utilities.ungzip`, and the ungzipped data might be able to be parsed with `Utilities.parseCsv`.

#### 3. Using your 3 requests, how about the following sample script?

```js
function exportjob2() {
  var accessToken = "###your access token###"; // Please set your access token.

  // 1st request: This is from https://stackoverflow.com/a/73032528
  var url1 = 'https://api.intercom.io/export/content/data';
  var options1 = {
    "method": "post",
    "headers": {
      "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken,
      "Accept": "application/json",
    },
    "contentType": "application/json",
    "payload": JSON.stringify({
      "created_at_after": 1654041600,
      "created_at_before": 1656547200
    })
  }
  var response1 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url1, options1);
  var { job_identifier } = JSON.parse(response1.getContentText());

  // 2nd request <--- Modified
  var url2 = 'https://api.intercom.io/export/content/data/' + job_identifier;
  var options2 = {
    "headers": {
      "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken,
      "Accept": "application/json",
    },
  }
  var response2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url2, options2);
  // console.log(response2.getContentText()); // for debug.
  var { download_url, status } = JSON.parse(response2.getContentText());
  while (status == "pending") {
    Utilities.sleep(5000); // Please adjust this value. The current wait time is 5 seconds.
    response2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url2, options2);
    // console.log(response2.getContentText()); // for debug.
    var obj = JSON.parse(response2.getContentText());
    status = obj.status;
    download_url = obj.download_url;
  }
  if (!download_url) {
    throw new Error("download_url has no value.");
  }

  // 3rd request
  var options3 = {
    "headers": {
      "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken,
      "Accept": "application/octet-stream",
    },
  }
  var response3 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(download_url, options3);
  var blob = response3.getBlob().setContentType("application/zip");
  var csvs = Utilities.unzip(blob);

  // Create a new Spreadsheet and put the CSV data to the 1st tab.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create("sample Spreadsheet");
  csvs.forEach((b, i) => {
    var ar = Utilities.parseCsv(b.getDataAsString());
    var sheet = i == 0 ? ss.getSheets()[i] : ss.insertSheet("sample" + (i + 1));
    sheet.getRange(1, 1, ar.length, ar[0].length).setValues(ar);
  });
}
```

- I'm not sure whether the downloaded the gzip file has the correct mimeType. So I added the mimeType like `var blob = response3.getBlob().setContentType("application/x-gzip")`.

#### Note:

- When this script is run, the flow of your showing question is done. But, I cannot test this API because I have no account. So, when an error occurs, please check each value and your access token again. And, please provide the error message. By this, I would like to confirm it.
- I thought that the value of `download_url` returned from the 1st request might be the same with the value of `download_url` returned from 2nd request. But, I cannot test this API because I have no account. So, please check it, and when my understanding is correct, you can modify the above script.
- This sample script creates a new Spreadsheet. But, if you want to put the CSV data to the existing Spreadsheet, please modify the above script.

#### Reference:

- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246647/discussion-on-answer-by-tanaike-convert-api-requests-to-google-apps-script).