# Intercom API requests to Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, intercom

I found this post while trying to solve my issue ([Convert API requests to Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73046039/convert-api-requests-to-google-apps-script)) but I am not familiar enough with the code to troubleshoot it.

I am basically looking for a similar solution - want to export my Intercom contacts (to get the Intercom ID which they do not make available via CSV export) to be able to merge and clean up my records. If anyone can help guide me with this task I would greatly appreciate it.

Via Postman I am able to connect to the API and get the data I need one contact at a time, but I am hoping to figure out how to export this as a CSV into Google sheets or something.

I tried the code posted on that previous post, but I get an error message:

Error: download_url has no value.

I am not familiar enough with this language nor API access to know how to work my way around this error.

Comment: Please share your code (not as image so we can easily copy your code) so we can easily replicate and better help you.